# Create Python setup

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have to create a setup screen with tk that starts only at the first boot of the application where you will have to enter names etc ... a sort of setup. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do so that A) is performed only the first time and B) the input can be saved and used in the other scripts? Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe use https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a file to store the details? You could use a text file or you could use pickle to save a python object then reload it. On starting your application you could check to see if the file exists and contains the necessary information, if it doesn't you can activate your setup screen, if not skip it.